# Get the name of the running php script in bash

Tags: php, bash, sh

I'm using a sendmail wrapper, but it prints only the path to the folder, not the running PHP script.

Is it possible to get the filename of the PHP script that invoked the shell script?

```
$(basename $0)
```

or

```
$(basename $(readlink -nf $0))
```

do not work. It shows me the "sendmail" filename.

Thanks.

Comment: Got anyone new ideas?

:))))))))

Comment: If you have control over how the shell script is invoked on the PHP side, perhaps you can try to use `putenv()` to set a custom environment variable to the value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ` and access that env. variable in your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try to run:
    `ps aux | grep php`

in command line and parse out the name of the file.

Comment: This gives only the path to php "/usr/bin/php5-cgi"